# One Hot Encoding for multiple columns in one go and appending to main dataset?

Tags: python, data-science

I am using below code in python to one-hot encode one of many categorical variables in my dataset. However, I want to encode multiple columns in one go but unable to do so. Also, these multiple columns have different # of categories Eg; one might have just a Yes and No but other columns have 4-5 different categories. How can I encode it all together using below code and append it in the main dataset?

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import argmax
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
# define example
  data = df[["column-name"]]
  values = array(data)
  print(values)
# integer encode
  label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
  integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
  print(integer_encoded)
# binary encode
  onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
  integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
  onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
  print(onehot_encoded)
```

Comment: Can you show how does the "data" look like?

Comment: col1 col2 col3
Yes Yes A
No Yes B
No No C 
Yes No F
Yes No A

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve what you want to do using pandas **get_dummies()** function. Try executing this code:

```
data = pd.get_dummies(data)
```

This will encode all the categorical variables and append it in the main dataframe.

Comment: That should work. Please go through the examples in documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: It definitely for single column character variables. Not for multiple. My question is for multiple columns.

Comment: There is a parameter called 'columns' in it which is by default none. Pass all the list of your columns here. You will get what you want.

Comment: Also, please check the third example. You don't even need to pass the column names.